# Symfony 2.6.3 {{ form_errors( form ) }} is blank when isValid() returns false

Tags: forms, symfony

I'm using Symfony V2.6.3

I have a simple form with three fields based on a Type class.

The Entity class that the Type class specifies via `setDefaultOptions()` has the `use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;` statement.

Each field has an `@Assert\NotBlank()` constraint in the Entity class.

CSRF is enabled.

HTML5 validation is disabled.

If I submit the form with all fields blank, the following happens:

- In the controller:

  - `isValid()` returns false
  - `getErrors( true )` returns an error for each field
- In the template:

  - `{{ form_errors( form ) }}` generates no text for the form or any of the fields.

I created a custom form theme and modified `{% block form_errors %}` to
dump the `errors` variable. The dump shows the `errors` property is a `FormErrorIterator` object with two properties: `form`, which is, I believe the field definition, and `errors` which is an empty array.

Oddly enough, drilling down into the `form` property reveals an `errors` property that is an array with a single `FormError` object that contains the error message.

This is not my first time using forms. It has worked just fine for me in the past. Could this be a new bug in 2.6?

I have searched for this and all I found were situations where `getErrors()` was also returning nothing.

Thanks in advance,
Dave

Comment: Perhaps you have `error_bubbling` disabled for the fields. `form_errors` only shows errors for the whole form or bubbled errors.

Comment: @sjagr beat me to it.   'error_bubbling' is false by default because standard convention is to have every field deal with it's own errors.

Comment: @DerickF Correct, you'd either have to use `form_errors` on the individual fields, turn on `error_bubbling` for each field, or use the full `form_widget` for the whole form or for the individual fields. Not `form_label` or `form_row`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay. I *finally* found the answer to this question.

Many thanks to thenetimp on the Symfony forum. He had the same problem and figured it out (http://forum.symfony-project.org/viewtopic.php?f=23&t=42841&p=135003&hilit=form_errors#p135003).

Turns out that you have to call createView() *after* calling isValid(). That actually makes sense when you think about it.

Answer (score 1):

Form errors are bound to a FormType, not to the complete Form. The RootType will only contain the errors that bubbled up from sub types. The sub types will only contain the errors of their type and the ones bubbled up from sub sub types, etc.

Doing `{{ form_errors(form) }}` will only render the errors of the root form. Assume there was an error on a `form.name` field, you can get this error by doing: `{{ form_errors(form.name) }}`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies. Form bubbling is, indeed off and I am looking at the errors for the individual fields. As I said, calling $form->getErrors( true ) (which returns child errors), yields the error text. It's just not available in the form.